# global.asax works on local computer but not after i publish to server

Tags: windows-server-2008, asp.net, deployment

i think this has been asked before but i just cannot figure this one out. I have added a global.asax file to my project (using asp.net with c# from vs2010) and works great on my local machine. then when i publish to our site (i publish to ftp site and then copy from the ftp folder into the site folder overwriting old files) and it doesn't work... at all. i am using 'windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise'. any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try setting your app pool to classic mode it may help. I had this problem and for what ever reason in integrated mode it never worked but as soon as i switched it to classic mode it did.